# How can I defeat a "Take No Damage" fairy chest challenge when there are spikes in the way?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've seen this situation numerous times. What rune/equipment do I need to have in order to get this thing?

[image: help plox]

Comment: Sky runes.  Probably at least two.  The platform's a red herring.

Comment: Not worth adding an answer for it, but potentially you could also find the Hermes Boots, which allow you walk on spikes. Not really something you can *plan* for though.

Comment: Dammit, I want this game now.

Comment: +1 for the hilarious mspaint work, and also for a good question.

Comment: You can also use the special item [`hermes' boots`](http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Items), which is sometimes given somewhere within the castle.

Comment: A few months later, I've encountered and successfully looted such a chest multiple times with a single Vault Rune...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are more ways of doing this one.

**Dragon class**

The easiest way would be to use a Dragon class as they can fly without any limit. That way you would just have to press A or S to fly, go down and fly to the chest.

I think it's needless to say that this approach will always have 100% success chance as it's impossible to mess it up.

**1 Dash 3x Vault Runes and no platform activation**

Hug the wall, drop down and dash left immediately, then use triple jump to reach the chest. This is also one of the easiest ways to do this.

**Hokage + 3x Vault Runes**

This is also an easy way without the need to activate the platform. Simply drop down and use your special ability to propel yourself forward the chest wall, then use triple jump to reach the chest itself.

--
There are more ways of doing this, but this three i mentioned are the easiest ones and none of them require platform activation.

Also note that you might actually need only 2 vault runes for second and third solution if your timing is good. But 3x vault runes will help you be 100% successful.

Answer (score 13):

You'll need a Sprint Rune (allows dashing) and a Vault Rune (allows multi-jumping) to retrieve this fairy chest. Basically, hug the wall, jump below the platform, immediately dash to the left, jump again while in mid-air, down-thrust the platform to open it up, and stand on it. Afterwards, double jump to reach the chest.

If you want to do it more safely, have two Sprint Runes equipped. I believe it can be done with one alone but, it's kind of risky.

Comment: The Hokage ability could also be used here. I am not sure if the assassin's fade out lets you run across spikes and take no damage while its active.. Might give it a go the next time I am an assassin.

Comment: If i remember right spikes will damage you even if you're using mist ability with assasin.

Comment: Yes, mist form does not help against spikes.

Answer (score 0):

All you actually need is a single vault rune.

The platform is not a red herring. I beat that room with only one vault and one dash rune equipped. You drop down, use the air jump to put you right above the platform and immediately downstrike it. Land on the top (this does take precision), then double jumpt to the chest.

I didnt even use the dash so this is totally doable with only a single vault rune.
(Granted the ways listed above will make it way easier... I just wanted to point out that it can be done very early in the game, without much farmed yet)

Comment: You're saying exactly the same thing as another existing answer.

Comment: Not really, since that answer says that you need at least one sprint rune... I was saying that it can be done with a single vault rune alone. In my book, that is a different method... otherwise almost every answer here is a repeat. Please actually read the entire answer and think before you try to say things are *exactly* the same